# Extracting element from list

Tags: r

```
fit <- lm(R1 ~ R2)
```

Yields...

```
Call:
lm(formula = R1 ~ R2)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.128139 -0.016528  0.000349  0.017806  0.125109 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.003785   0.001884   2.009   0.0453 *  
R.2         0.949923   0.043904  21.636   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I have run an linear regression with these results. Now I want to collect one value, more precisely: fit["coefficients" -> "(Intercept)"].

I try

```
fit["coefficients"]
```

which yields

```
$coefficients
(Intercept)   R2 
0.003785144 0.949923219
```

How could I extract this 1 value?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try this: `fit$coefficients[[1]]` or `summary(fit)$coef[1,1]` .

Comment: That worked! Thank you!!!

Comment: `fit$coefficients[1]` would also work, though the result would be named. You could also use recursive indexing `fit[[c("coefficients", "(intercept)")]]`.

Comment: @lmo the second example should read ..."(Intercept)" .... Sorry for the splitting hairs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `coef()` allow to extract coefficients from a `lm` object. So to get the intercept value, you simply have to use

```
coef(fit)[1]
```